# Wait for element to be visible in Protractor

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, protractor

I spent a couple days trying to make Protractor click elements that are visible on the page appearing after a click on a button. But most of the time I have this error:

```
  Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
  Stack:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
        at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11)
        at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
        at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:290:5)
```

I tried a couple things so far:

- `browser.waitForAngular` was blocking the script, even though I could
  see I was on the second page.
- Multiple `browser.driver.wait` implementation, like this one:

  browser.driver.wait(EC.visibilityOf($('li.unsigned')), 10000).then(() => {
    element($('li.unsigned')).click();
  })
- `protractor.ExpectedConditions` as you can see above, which did not work as well.
- I also added an option in my onPrepare script to manage implicitWait, like so:

  onPrepare: function () {
      browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15000);

The only way I got it to work was to remove everything I tried and use a browser.sleep(10000) before trying to click the element.

If anybody has an idea of what could cause the issue, or what else I could try, you're welcome!

Comment: did you tried overriding jasmine default timeout parameter
        jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 900000;

Comment: I guess it was working while I testing multiple things. You can check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

even I had similar issue and I added these lines in my config

```
 jasmineNodeOpts: {
// Default time to wait in ms before a test fails.
   defaultTimeoutInterval: 250000
},
allScriptsTimeout: 180000
```

and in my specs

```
var originalTimeout;  
beforeEach(function () {
originalTimeout = jasmine.defaultTimeoutInterval;
jasmine.defaultTimeoutInterval = 50000;
});

it("texttobe", function(){
}

afterEach(function () {
jasmine.defaultTimeoutInterval = originalTimeout;
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure this would help, since the page was loading before the timeout would end, which makes me think of an implicit wait issue. If the issue comes back, I'll try your solution.

Answer (score 0):

So, after playing a bit more with my code, I got it to work with just the addition to the `onPrepare` in `protractor.conf.js`:

```
  onPrepare: function () {
    browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30000);
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: './tsconfig.e2e.json'
    });
  }
```

And by doing a `browser.driver.findElement(by.css(element)).then()`.

Having the ExpectedConditions with the implicitWait created an issue that resulted in the timeout though, but I don't know the reason why.

Comment: Yes it's not advisable to use both waits with each other as implicit wait is set for complete driver life. Try going through selenium docs for implicit wait. Using .then means you are resolving promise correctly as javascript is asynchronous..

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve an element with the following:

```js
const elem = browser.element(by.css("div#target")); // use "browser.element.all" to get multiple elements
```

Or its equivalent:

```js
const elem = browser.$("div#target"); // use "browser.$$" to get multiple elements
```

Then wait for it to be visible:

```js
await browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(elem), 10000); // 10s timeout
```